# Passing the value of a common controls checkbox to a javascript flag

Tags: javascript, jsp, common-controls

If I have an editable checkbox defined in a table as follows:

```
<ctrl:columncheckbox title="Delete" 
                     property="delete" 
                     styleId="delete" 
                     editable="true" 
                     onchange="setFlag();"/>
```

How would I go about passing the value of the checkbox to a boolean that I've defined in javascript? I.e. what should the "setFlag()" function look like?

Thank you for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using some server-side control to render the checkbox.  In most cases, you would look up whether or not a checkbox is checked using its id attribute, which does not appear to be specified in the code you provided.  Look at the actual HTML that is rendered.  It should look something like this: `<input type='checkbox' id='foo' />`.  Your Javascript might look something like this.

```
var isChecked = document.getElementById('foo').checked
```

If you are talking about a whole column of checkboxes, as your code suggests, you might want to look into something like jQuery that has a rich API for looking up various elements on the page.

Comment: I believe the styleId property sets the id with this particular technology. Thanks for the reply

Comment: One thing that I've run into working with ASP.net is that the the framework might refer to an ID server-side that is different from what gets set in the ID attribute in HTML.  Watch out for this!